# Shadow map draws

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, shader, shadow

After literally 3 days of finding out how to do shadowmaps without it going mental I finally reached a stage where it's acutally a visible shadow map. But now I have one last problem with some strange appearances of objects on places where it's impossible to be (At least in normal life).

#### The problem I have is this:

I draw 3 test objects in the scene a sphere, a weird blocky guy, and a smaller version of that blocky guy.
The sphere is basicly the closest to the light, so you won't expect the shadow of the big guy to appear on it.
The small guy is hovering in the air.
The big guy's shadow is on the correct position(He's also at position 0,0,0 in world coordinates), but has the sphere's shadow all over him on places which don't make sense.

This is the first image:

### [image: First]

And the second one where I moved the big guy to a further location:

### [image: Second]

As you can see on the second image the shadow is also no longer on the sphere.

The order in which I draw them is Sphere -> Big guy -> Small guy
I also send the current ModelView matrix to the shader just before I draw each object

```
    Sphere s = new Sphere();
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(100,150,-100);
    s.draw(50, 36, 36);
    glPopMatrix();
    
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-50,0,50);
    glScalef(0.1f,0.1f,0.1f);
    glColor3f(1f,195f/255f,0f);
    drawBot();
    glPopMatrix();
    
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0,0,100);
    glRotatef(180,0,1,0);
    glScalef(0.01f,0.01f,0.01f);
    glColor3f(0,114f/255f,1f);
    drawBot();
    glPopMatrix();
```

This is my vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

uniform mat4 lightP, lightMV, camP, camMV, bias, curMV;

out vec4 shadowCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = (camP*curMV) * gl_Vertex;
    gl_Position.z-=0.01;
    shadowCoord = (bias*(lightP*lightMV)) * (gl_Vertex);
}
```

This is my fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

uniform sampler2D shadowMapTexture;

in vec4 shadowCoord;

out vec4 oColor;

float shadowMapping(){
    float visibility = 0.0;
    float bias = 0.01;

    vec3 shadowPos = shadowCoord.xyz/shadowCoord.w;
    if (texture2D( shadowMapTexture, shadowPos.xy ).z  < shadowPos.z-bias){
        visibility = 0.5;
    }
    return visibility;
}

void main(){
    float shade = shadowMapping();
    oColor = vec4(0,0,0,shade);
}
```

Is there anyone who understands this riddle?

Comment: `gl_Vertex` and `texture2D(...)` are not valid in a 330 core shader. Is your GLSL compiler at least warning you about these things? The shader should be written as `330 compatibility`, but that's really not your problem here.

Comment: I'll put the compatibility in anyways, thanks! I'll look into some things about the core vs compatibility too, always good to know about!

Comment: Where do the matrices in your vertex shader come from? You are using fixed function matrix methods when drawing and I dont see any code that sets these uniforms.

Comment: ShadowCoord= shadowTextureMatrix * inverse(SceneMatrix) * ModelMatrix) * gl_Vertex; where shadowTexMat holds bias and translation of shadow map, sceneMatrix is your ModelView for the whole scene and ModelMatrix is the modelViewMatrix for each object.

Comment: Thanks @j-p ! Changing 
`shadowCoord = (bias*(lightP*lightMV)) * (gl_Vertex);`
to

`shadowCoord = (bias*(lightP*lightMV)) * (inverse(camMV)*curMV) * (gl_Vertex);`
worked!